# Oracle: failed to fetch data ZABBIX

Tags: linux, database, oracle, oracle11g, zabbix

So i am trying to monitor oracle database replication using zabbix,

my setup is:

1. oracle database 11g r2
2. zabbix 5.4

i did install ODBC client in zabbix server and follow [this step](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/oracle_odbc/README.md?at=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F5.4), my zabbix server can connect with my oracle database via ODBC. But, when i add template 'Oracle Database by ODBC' i got this error:
[image]
i already set host macros, here's the configuration:
[image]
i turn off firewall, disable selinux, but it's still can fetch data from my database..
can someone help me? **or maybe now zabbix doesn't support monitoring oracle database 11g?**

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This setup does not support oracle 11. I am pretty sure the template could be adjusted for that but you do need some oracle and zabbix knowledge to get that working.

Years ago I created https://github.com/ikzelf/zbxdb and that does support about each and every release I could find. It is quite a different setup but it also supports more advanced oracle configurations. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: ini here:
To do that, create a simple OS user that has the ability to use cron, zabbix_sender and is able to connect to the server or proxy port, as wel as a creating a connection to the remote database[s]. For example create user zbxdb.

can i create zbxdb in zabbix server?

Comment: You can run zbxdb from the zabbix server or from the zabbix proxies. Yes.